# How can I format this file as a list of lists of coordinates that I can draw in matplotlib?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, file-io, graphics

I have a file with coordinates to draw neighborhoods. Each pair of coordinates is separated by a pipe | and each neighborhood is separated by a plus + . I have a file containing lines like the following:

```
40.742742,-73.993847|40.739389,-73.985667|40.74715499999999,-73.97992|40.750573,-73.988415|40.742742,-73.993847+40.734706,-73.991915|40.736917,-73.990263|40.736104,-73.98846|40.740315,-73.985263|40.74364800000001,-73.993353|40.73729099999999,-73.997988|40.734706,-73.991915+40.729226,-74.003463|40.7214529,-74.006038|40.717745,-74.000389|40.722299,-73.996634|40.725291,-73.994413|40.729226,-74.003463
40.75905000000001,-73.992917|40.75330999999999,-73.997111|40.747842,-73.984165|40.750541,-73.982105|40.7536289,-73.979873|40.75905000000001,-73.992917+40.734706,-73.991915|40.736917,-73.990263|40.736104,-73.98846|40.740315,-73.985263|40.74364800000001,-73.993353|40.73729099999999,-73.997988|40.734706,-73.991915+40.76522500000001,-73.988411|40.761590000000005,-73.979911|40.75479899999999,-73.985196|40.753337,-73.981633|40.748297,-73.985624|40.745534,-73.979058|40.751012,-73.975218|40.7623729,-73.967169|40.76874000000001,-73.982489|40.767305,-73.983433|40.76845,-73.985873|40.76522500000001,-73.988411
40.742742,-73.993847|40.739389,-73.985667|40.74715499999999,-73.97992|40.750573,-73.988415|40.742742,-73.993847+40.75065,-74.00914|40.74859,-74.00845|40.74211100000001,-74.009657|40.736667,-73.99649800000002|40.747337,-73.988864|40.75538,-74.007445|40.75065,-74.00914+40.734706,-73.991915|40.736917,-73.990263|40.736104,-73.98846|40.740315,-73.985263|40.74364800000001,-73.993353|40.73729099999999,-73.997988|40.734706,-73.991915
```

Assuming the above is the whole file, I'd like the following output:

```
[[[40.742742,-73.993847], [40.739389,-73.985667], [40.74715499999999,-73.97992], [40.750573,-73.988415], [40.742742,-73.993847]], [[40.734706,-73.991915], [40.736917,-73.990263], [40.736104,-73.98846], [40.740315,-73.985263], [40.74364800000001,-73.993353], [40.73729099999999,-73.997988], [40.734706,-73.991915]], [[40.729226,-74.003463], [40.7214529,-74.006038], [40.717745,-74.000389], [40.722299,-73.996634], [40.725291,-73.994413], [40.729226,-74.003463]], [[40.75905000000001,-73.992917], [40.75330999999999,-73.997111], [40.747842,-73.984165], [40.750541,-73.982105], [40.7536289,-73.979873], [40.75905000000001,-73.992917]], [[40.734706,-73.991915], [40.736917,-73.990263], [40.736104,-73.98846], [40.740315,-73.985263], [40.74364800000001,-73.993353], [40.73729099999999,-73.997988], [40.734706,-73.991915]], [[40.76522500000001,-73.988411], [40.761590000000005,-73.979911], [40.75479899999999,-73.985196], [40.753337,-73.981633], [40.748297,-73.985624], [40.745534,-73.979058], [40.751012,-73.975218], [40.7623729,-73.967169], [40.76874000000001,-73.982489], [40.767305,-73.983433], [40.76845,-73.985873], [40.76522500000001,-73.988411]], [[40.742742,-73.993847], [40.739389,-73.985667], [40.74715499999999,-73.97992], [40.750573,-73.988415], [40.742742,-73.993847]], [[40.75065,-74.00914], [40.74859,-74.00845], [40.74211100000001,-74.009657], [40.736667,-73.99649800000002], [40.747337,-73.988864], [40.75538,-74.007445], [40.75065,-74.00914]], [[40.734706,-73.991915], [40.736917,-73.990263], [40.736104,-73.98846], [40.740315,-73.985263], [40.74364800000001,-73.993353], [40.73729099999999,-73.997988], [40.734706,-73.991915]]]
```

I can draw a picture of manhattan in matplotlib using the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mVerts = []
with open('Manhattan_Coords.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        pair = [float(s) for s in line.strip()[1:-1].split(", ")]
        mVerts.append(pair)

plt.plot(*zip(*mVerts))
plt.show()
```

The file `Manhattan_Coords.txt` contains lines like the following:

```
[-74.0104294, 40.6996416]
[-74.0048504, 40.701854]
[-74.0000439, 40.7046519]
```

I need to keep each neighborhood as a separate polygon which in my file is separated by a `+` or a newline (both ways are used in the file)

Comment: what shape you expect that your file to be ?

Comment: You have  "I have a file containing lines like the following" and "The file Manhattan_Coords.txt contains lines like the following:", which is your actual input and what output do you want?

Comment: The first set of coordinates (with the pipes and plus signs) is my input. I want an output that can be hopefully read in a similar fashion to how I drew manhattan, so that I can draw all the neighborhoods on top of my manhattan map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to split into groups  based on a `newline` or a `+`

```
import re
with open('Manhattan_Coords.txt') as f:
      sections = ([list(map(float, (ele.split(","))))
             for li in (x.split("|")
                        for x in re.split("\n|\+", f.read().replace("-", "-0").replace("-\\r", "0").rstrip()))
             for ele in li])
  [[40.742742, -73.993847], [40.739389, -73.985667], [40.74715499999999, -73.97992], [40.750573, -73.988415], [40.742742, -73.993847], [40.734706, -73.991915], [40.736917, -73.990263], [40.736104, -73.98846], [40.740315, -73.985263], [40.74364800000001, -73.993353], [40.73729099999999, -73.997988], [40.734706, -73.991915], [40.729226, -74.003463], [40.7214529, -74.006038], [40.717745, -74.000389], [40.722299, -73.996634], [40.725291, -73.994413], [40.729226, -74.003463], [40.75905000000001, -73.992917], [40.75330999999999, -73.997111], [40.747842, -73.984165], [40.750541, -73.982105], [40.7536289, -73.979873], [40.75905000000001, -73.992917], [40.734706, -73.991915], [40.736917, -73.990263], [40.736104, -73.98846], [40.740315, -73.985263], [40.74364800000001, -73.993353], [40.73729099999999, -73.997988], [40.734706, -73.991915], [40.76522500000001, -73.988411], [40.761590000000005, -73.979911], [40.75479899999999, -73.985196], [40.753337, -73.981633], [40.748297, -73.985624], [40.745534, -73.979058], [40.751012, -73.975218], [40.7623729, -73.967169], [40.76874000000001, -73.982489], [40.767305, -73.983433], [40.76845, -73.985873], [40.76522500000001, -73.988411], [40.742742, -73.993847], [40.739389, -73.985667], [40.74715499999999, -73.97992], [40.750573, -73.988415], [40.742742, -73.993847], [40.75065, -74.00914], [40.74859, -74.00845], [40.74211100000001, -74.009657], [40.736667, -73.99649800000002], [40.747337, -73.988864], [40.75538, -74.007445], [40.75065, -74.00914], [40.734706, -73.991915], [40.736917, -73.990263], [40.736104, -73.98846], [40.740315, -73.985263], [40.74364800000001, -73.993353], [40.73729099999999, -73.997988], [40.734706, -73.991915]]
```

Comment: Is there a way to make each of the coordinate pairs actual pairs? (40* and -73* is a pair)

Comment: You do want them grouped in sections separated by a newline or + yes? Add your expected output from the first line.

Comment: (I added it into the question now)

Comment: All I get is a large list of map objects??

Comment: one sec, just saw python 3 tag

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Neighborhood_Coords_Extract.py", line 8, in <module>
    print([list(map(float,ele.split(","))) for li in (x.split("|") for x in re.split("\n|\+",f.read())) for ele in li])
  File "Neighborhood_Coords_Extract.py", line 8, in <listcomp>
    print([list(map(float,ele.split(","))) for li in (x.split("|") for x in re.split("\n|\+",f.read())) for ele in li])
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '[-74.0104294'

Comment: The code runs fine for me and I get the output as posted in my answer , what file are you running the code on?

Comment: you had some empty and mismatched sized sections in your data, it should  work now fine

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Neighborhood_Coords_Extract.py", line 10, in <module>
    for x in re.split("\n|\+", f.read().replace("\\r","0"))) for ele in li]
  File "Neighborhood_Coords_Extract.py", line 10, in <listcomp>
    for x in re.split("\n|\+", f.read().replace("\\r","0"))) for ele in li]
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-'